# jQuery Treeview - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeview is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я хочу создать админку сайта, там у меня есть вертикальное меню. Мне нужно, чтоб при нажатии на картинку "плюсик"  перед названием категории, ниже открывались подкатегории, а картинка "плюс" менялась на "минус".

**Вот демоверсия**
[image: Демоверсия]

Вот что у меня получилось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это попробовала сделать с помощью плагина – **jQuery Treeview**. 
В внутри тега `header` подключила библиотеки

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-treeview-master/jquery.treeview.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-treeview-master/jquery.treeview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#navigation").treeview({
             collapsed: true, //по умолчанию свернуто
             animated: 100 //анимация
        });
    });
</script>
```

В теге `body` у меня есть список (`ul id="navigation"`):

Folder 1

- Item 1.1

Folder 2

- Subfolder 2.1

  File 2.1.1

  File 2.1.2

File 2.2

Folder 3 (closed at start)

- File 3.1

File 4

**Ошибка**

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeview is not a function

на этой строке `$("#navigation").treeview({"`

Comment: приведите Ваш код и напишите в чем у Вас ошибка или затруднение.

Comment: похоже библиотека treeview не подключена. Убедитесь, что `src="jquery-treeview-master/jquery.treeview.js"` правильный путь относительно файла, где вы работаете...

Comment: Дело в том что библиотека правильно подключена, демоверсия работает.

Comment: демо версия может работать потому что билиотека правильно подключена относительно демо файла... Попробуйте, будучи в файле, где у Вас `treeview` поставить в адресную строку `jquery-treeview-master/jquery.treeview.js`. Если Вы увидите JS код - тогда да, все правильно. Если же нет - значит нет связи между Вашим текущим файлом и этим JS

Comment: @Alex Да. Ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeview is not a function " на этой строке$("#navigation").treeview({ –

Comment: @Anastasiya Ваша проблема была в том, что Вы пытались подключить 3 разных версии jquery, ввиду этого Вы версию jquery, не характерную для плагина. ответ написали ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе просмотренных файлов,
проблема заключается в том, что Вы пытаетесь зачем то подключить 3 версии jquery:

1 - строка 14 - `<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>`;

2 - строка 20 - `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>`;

3 - строка 200 - `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Все эти подключения удалите  и добавьте в шапку(между `<head></head>` нормальное подключение последнее версии jquery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

P.S.: проблема в том, что, в конечном счете, из-за всех этих ненужных подключений, Вы подключаете версию `jquery` несовместимую с плагином.

Comment: Да. Все заработало)) А подскажите, пожалуйста еще, как можно    сделать красивую админку,  как здесь "indexZagranisa.php" ?

Comment: для этого Вам нужно более менее разбираться в html и css, а так это обширный вопрос. Впрочем никто не мешает просто скопировать стили.

Comment: Вы думаете, это сделано только стилями, никаких скриптов не было использовано?

Comment: @Anastasiya css и jquery - просто откройте файл и посмотрите какая там реализация